# Convert a Canvas element into Image element

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I have a website where I need to generate dynamic images specific to the user. The approach I found was using `canvas`. I have text information and image file which need to be copied to the canvas and then, later on, can be converted to the image file which the user can download.

```js
function generateImage() {
    let event_date = '11-02-2022'
    let event_name = 'Prom Night'

    let canvas = document.getElementById("your-canvas")
    let ctx = canvas.getContext("2d")

    ctx.font = "26px Arial";
    ctx.textAlign = 'center'

    // For Heading
    ctx.fillText(event_date + ' - ' + event_name, 400, 50)

    var img = new Image();
    img.onload = function () {
        ctx.drawImage(img, 100, 100);
    }
    img.src = 'https://cdn.sstatic.net/stackexchange/img/logos/so/so-icon.png'
    return canvas.toDataURL('image/jpg')
}

// generateImage()
let image_gen = generateImage()
$('#gen-image').attr('src', image_gen)
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.js"
        integrity="sha256-H+K7U5CnXl1h5ywQfKtSj8PCmoN9aaq30gDh27Xc0jk=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<center>
  <h1>CANVAS ELEMENT</h1>
</center>
<br>
<canvas id="your-canvas" width="1000" height="400"></canvas>
<center>
  <h1>IMAGE ELEMENT</h1>
</center>
<br>
<img src="" id="gen-image" alt="" style="border: 0.1em solid black;">
```

As you can see in the snippet that the image is visible and copied successfully into the canvas but not visible when the `canvas` is converted into `img` with `toDataURL()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Loading an Image can take some time. In your code, `toDataURL` is returned before image is loaded and painted on canvas.

To *resolve* this, you can use [Promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) to wait until the image is loaded and then get the URL of the canvas.

```js
function generateImage() {
  const promise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    let event_date = "11-02-2022";
    let event_name = "Prom Night";

    let canvas = document.getElementById("your-canvas");
    let ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

    ctx.font = "26px Arial";
    ctx.textAlign = "center";

    // For Heading
    ctx.fillText(event_date + " - " + event_name, 400, 50);

    var img = new Image();
    img.setAttribute("crossorigin", "anonymous");
    img.src = "https://picsum.photos/200/300";
    img.onload = () => {
      ctx.drawImage(img, 100, 100);
      resolve(canvas.toDataURL("image/jpg"));
    };
  });
  return promise;
}

generateImage().then((value) => {
  $("#gen-image").attr("src", value);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.js" integrity="sha256-H+K7U5CnXl1h5ywQfKtSj8PCmoN9aaq30gDh27Xc0jk=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<center>
  <h1>CANVAS ELEMENT</h1>
</center>
<br>
<canvas id="your-canvas" width="1000" height="400"></canvas>
<center>
  <h1>IMAGE ELEMENT</h1>
</center>
<br>
<img src="" id="gen-image" alt="" style="border: 0.1em solid black;">
```

Comment: I was thinking to use Promise function for this but in a different way. But this works like a charm

Comment: Hey, what if I want to add 2 images to the canvas. I wrote this line `resolve(canvas.toDataURL("image/jpg"));` inside another image's `onload` function. But this load only one image at a time.

Comment: Try with [Promise.all](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all)